# Voice to text in Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any way to enable voice to text (speech recognition) in gmail when using Chrome as a webbrowser? I really like the feature to search at google.com via voice and I'd also love to speak my mails instead of typing. I tried several chrome extensions, e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speech-recognition-for-gm/ffnepgjlfiinpkplhjmehkdhnaaongdk?hl=d
but none worked. I don't know why because the feature would be the same because the voice recognition API obviously already exists; so it should be easy to make it useable in gmail also!? At least from googles point of view...
Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't anybody ever think of it as well? :(

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go here to use Google's "Web Speech API Demonstration" -- it works very fast and well and in multiple languages:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

There's even a "Create Email" button!

**Update**: I couldn't resist, so I wrote a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-dictation/eggdmhdpffgikgakkfojgiledkekfdce) that does exactly this. Try it out and let me know. :-)

Comment: Very nice indeed! Thx

Answer (score 2):

On Windows and Mac you can use the speech recognition software [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm) (I'm writing this answer with it, as well as all my e-mails, reports, etc., even [coding](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/3605/2476) to some extent). On Linux there [exist](http://www.linux.com/news/embedded-mobile/mobile-linux/711479-palaver-taps-googles-voice-technology-for-linux-speech-recognition/) some programs tapping Google's voice technology but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I know that software, it's quite good, but I didn't like it because it's a little bit bloated. I thought it would be possible to simply have a voice recognition by google (the same used for the google search) built-into the browser (recognizing your voice on their servers) :(

Answer (score 2):

With the Chrome Extension "Checker Plus for Gmail" http://goo.gl/nOIov4 you can do this.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the answers and existing solutions have suffered from bit rot.

As of mid-2015, the "virtual keyboard" in Chrome will take voice input, and it works with any input field (including Gmail).  See:  https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6076237?hl=en&source=genius-rts

Comment: Looks like a Chromebook-only feature. For Chrome, Google released [Input Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab?hl=en) that support only hand entry. All voice apps for Chrome are made by third parties.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some developers use the Google Translate Voice to include it in their games.

Either because they want to call the player by their name or making a piece of code for their game would be too hard. If the Internet is disconnected while you play the Java/Flash game, it's less impressive.

A *modder* for Half-Life 2 created a mod where all the dialogue for the NPCs was generated by Google Translate.

The Lazy solution is the way to go.